# How to import data to GridView Using Linq To Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

I want to import data to `gridview` from `Excel`. And I have done using `System.Data.OleDb` as

```
if (ExlSheet.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(ExlSheet.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(ExlSheet.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
            ExlSheet.SaveAs(fileLocation);
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                  fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                  fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
            dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
            gv.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
            gv.DataBind(); 
        }
```

How to achieve the same using `LinqToExcel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 if (ExlSheet.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(ExlSheet.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(ExlSheet.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
            ExlSheet.SaveAs(fileLocation);
            ExcelQueryFactory excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileLocation);

            var data = from a in excelFile.Worksheet("Sheet1") select a;


            var columnNames = excelFile.GetColumnNames("Sheet1");
            DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
            foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
            {
                dtExcelRecords.Columns.Add(columnName);
            }
            foreach (var row in data)
            {
                DataRow dr = dtExcelRecords.NewRow();
                foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    dr[columnName] = row[columnName];
                }
                dtExcelRecords.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            gv.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
```